# Switch numbering in Algorithm from \arabic to \arabic\alpha for specific lines

Tags: numbering, algorithm2e

Switch numbering in Algorithm from `\arabic` to `\arabic\alpha` for specific lines

In the code below, I wanted to change `#3` to `3a` and `#4` to `3b`.  Then number `5` should be `#4`.  Basically, I wanted to change just `3-4` to `3a` and `3b` and then resume numbering as normal.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm, bm}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\newcommand\mycommfont[1]{\footnotesize\ttfamily\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\SetCommentSty{mycommfont}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}


\makeatletter
\def\munderbar#1{\underline{\sbox\tw@{$#1$}\dp\tw@\z@\box\tw@}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nosemic}{\renewcommand{\@endalgocfline}{\relax}}% Drop semi-colon ;
\newcommand{\dosemic}{\renewcommand{\@endalgocfline}{\algocf@endline}}% Reinstate semi-colon ;
\newcommand{\pushline}{\Indp}% Indent
\newcommand{\popline}{\Indm\dosemic}% Undent
\let\oldnl\nl% Store \nl in \oldnl
\newcommand{\nonl}{\renewcommand{\nl}{\let\nl\oldnl}}% Remove line number for one line
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\colorbox{mybluei!05}{\color{black}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\SetAlgoLined
\SetNlSty{textbf}{}{:}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
\nonl{Assume that there is a set of $M$ face images}
\begin{equation*}
  \left\{\Gamma_{1}, \Gamma_{2},...,\Gamma_{M},  \right\}
\end{equation*}
Each image has the size of $r \times c$\\
$r\rightarrow \# ~\text{of rows}\quad c \rightarrow \#~ \text{of columns}$\\
Averaging face images
\begin{equation*}
  \Psi = \dfrac{1}{M}\sum_{i=1}^{M} \Gamma_{i}
\end{equation*}\\
Remove the average image from all given ones
\begin{equation*}
  \circled{H}_{i} = \Gamma_{i} - \Psi \quad i = 1,2,...,M
\end{equation*}\\
Convert $\underset{\text{dim}}{ r \times c}$ images into $\underset{\text{dim}}{ \rho \times 1}$ vectors, where $\rho = r \times c$ using a raster scan.
\begin{equation*}
\hspace{1cm}\circled{H}_{i} \Rightarrow \bm{\munderbar{x}}_{i}\hspace{2cm}i=1,2,...,M
\end{equation*}\\
Stack $M$ vectors into a matrix
\begin{equation*}
X = \left[\bm{\munderbar{x}}_{1},\bm{\munderbar{x}}_{2},...,\bm{\munderbar{x}}_{M} \right]
\end{equation*}
where $X$ is a $\rho \times M$ matrix.\\
Compute matrix R from $X$.
\begin{equation*}
  R=\frac{1}{M}X'X\quad (\text{much smaller than $XX'$})
\end{equation*}
where $R$ is $M\times M$ \hspace{1cm} $M\ll P$
\caption{Principal Component Analysis (PCA) Training}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my point of view this is best achieved with a `SubAlgoLine` counter and an conditional within `\theAlgoLine` (which prints the line number)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm, bm}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\newcommand\mycommfont[1]{\footnotesize\ttfamily\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\SetCommentSty{mycommfont}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}


\makeatletter
\def\munderbar#1{\underline{\sbox\tw@{$#1$}\dp\tw@\z@\box\tw@}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nosemic}{\renewcommand{\@endalgocfline}{\relax}}% Drop semi-colon ;
\newcommand{\dosemic}{\renewcommand{\@endalgocfline}{\algocf@endline}}% Reinstate semi-colon ;
\newcommand{\pushline}{\Indp}% Indent
\newcommand{\popline}{\Indm\dosemic}% Undent
\let\oldnl\nl% Store \nl in \oldnl
\newcommand{\nonl}{\renewcommand{\nl}{\let\nl\oldnl}}% Remove line number for one line

\let\@@thealgoline\theAlgoLine
\newif\ifuseothernumbering
\newcounter{SubAlgoLine}
\renewcommand{\theSubAlgoLine}{\@@thealgoline\alph{SubAlgoLine}}
\renewcommand{\theAlgoLine}{%
  \ifuseothernumbering
  \ifnum\c@AlgoLine=3
  \protect\refstepcounter{SubAlgoLine}
  \theSubAlgoLine%
  \else
  \ifnum\c@AlgoLine=4
  \protect\refstepcounter{SubAlgoLine}  
  \addtocounter{AlgoLine}{\m@ne}%
  \theSubAlgoLine%
  \global\useothernumberingfalse
  \else
  \@@thealgoline%
  \fi
  \fi
  \else
  \@@thealgoline%  
  \fi
}



\makeatother

\begin{document}

\colorbox{mybluei!05}{\color{black}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\SetAlgoLined
\SetNlSty{textbf}{}{:}
\useothernumberingtrue
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
\nonl{Assume that there is a set of $M$ face images}
\begin{equation*}
  \left\{\Gamma_{1}, \Gamma_{2},...,\Gamma_{M},  \right\}
\end{equation*}
Each image has the size of $r \times c$\\
$r\rightarrow \# ~\text{of rows}\quad c \rightarrow \#~ \text{of columns}$\\
Averaging face images
\begin{equation*}
  \Psi = \dfrac{1}{M}\sum_{i=1}^{M} \Gamma_{i}
\end{equation*}\\
Remove the average image from all given ones
\begin{equation*}
  \circled{H}_{i} = \Gamma_{i} - \Psi \quad i = 1,2,...,M
\end{equation*}\\
Convert $\underset{\text{dim}}{ r \times c}$ images into $\underset{\text{dim}}{ \rho \times 1}$ vectors, where $\rho = r \times c$ using a raster scan.
\begin{equation*}
\hspace{1cm}\circled{H}_{i} \Rightarrow \bm{\munderbar{x}}_{i}\hspace{2cm}i=1,2,...,M
\end{equation*}\\
Stack $M$ vectors into a matrix
\begin{equation*}
X = \left[\bm{\munderbar{x}}_{1},\bm{\munderbar{x}}_{2},...,\bm{\munderbar{x}}_{M} \right]
\end{equation*}
where $X$ is a $\rho \times M$ matrix.\\
Compute matrix R from $X$.
\begin{equation*}
  R=\frac{1}{M}X'X\quad (\text{much smaller than $XX'$})
\end{equation*}
where $R$ is $M\times M$ \hspace{1cm} $M\ll P$
\caption{Principal Component Analysis (PCA) Training}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I sincerely appreciate it.  Your solution works perfect standalone, however, when I try to `\include` a chapter that has your solution as an `\input`, I get the error `! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }`.  Can you tell me how I can go about fixing this?  Thanks again!

Comment: @Joe: Well, that's another question

Comment: Thanks, I put the new post http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306489/compilation-error-after-running-algorithm2e-in-document

Comment: I have been trying all night to get the code to corporate.  At your convenience, can you possibly direct me as to what may be wrong with the code?  Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Joe: I'll try,but honestly, I can't see where the problem at the moment. It does not compile, alright, but the source of the error is incomprehensible to me at the moment

Comment: The updated post reflects the error discussed.  Thanks for looking into this.  I sincerely appreciate it!